# Empty Asterisk 12 CDRs in SQLite3 database

Tags: linux, asterisk, sqlite

Using:

- CentOS 6
- Asterisk 12
- cdr_sqlite3_custom.so

cdr_sqlite3_custom.conf (deliberately simplified):

> ```
> [master]
> table=>cdr
> columns=>calldate, clid, test
> values=>'${CDR(start)}','${CDR(clid)}','test'
> ```

Resulting in database lacking CDR values:

```
sqlite> select * from cdr;
AcctId|calldate|clid|test
1|||test
2|||test
3|||test
4|||test
```

IDs are incementing, test value is there, but it doesn't want to grab CDR variables from values=>'${CDR(start)}','${CDR(clid)}','test'

Any ideas where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer on IRC confirmed it as a bug.

Filed a bugreport:
https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-23162